# Connecting ASP on Azure Virtual Machine to Azure Db

Tags: azure, asp-classic

Has anyone ever connected ASP (ASP, aka classic not .NET) to an Azure db? I've had three experts looks at connection strings, endpoints, firewalls, db accounts and they're finding

1. the database works and contains data
2. the database is accessible remotely by our local machines via Visual Studio and SQL Server Manager
3. ASP runs on web server on the VM machine
4. All the connection strings offered by Azure fail
5. All db related ports are open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're connecting to the Azure DB from SSMS, everything is probably configured properly.

Which client library are you using to connect to the Azure SQL instance? You may need to download and install the MS SQL Native Client on the VM, which I know works.

Are you using ADO in your app? If so, and assuming you have installed the Native Client, this connection string will work:

Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net; Database=myDataBase;Uid=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Pwd=myPassword;Encrypt=yes;

Comment: This worked! Thanks, DanielG!

I found I had an outdated driver, SQL Native Client 10.0 instead of 11.0 and that was causing the issue, but this advice got me there. The 64-but driver update, as of now for Azure VMs, is available here [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409)

Comment: Awesome! Kindest regards

Comment: We ran into issues using this ODBC connection string and Azure SQL. In stored procedures, ODBC was converting TINYINTs to vartype 16, which caused type mismatch errors. We switched to OLE DB and the errors went away. Example OLE DB connection string: Provider=SQLNCLI11;Password=myPassword;User ID=[username]@[servername];
Initial Catalog=databasename;Data Source=tcp:[servername].database.windows.net;